# Extra filed doesn't giving me any error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

```
select *, min(salary), manager, em_name
from emp_table
group by manager
```

I am using this query and it executed successfully . why it doesn't give me an error saying that em_name or other column should be in group by clause

this my table structure--

[image: table structure]

Comment: Is manager the primary key? (Or unique constraint.) If yes, the query is valid. Otherwise you should have an exception.

Comment: Please tag the correct RDBMS and **only** the correct RDBMS. SQL Server and MySQL are 2 completely different products.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: no manager is not a primary key but it executed successfully ..

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: It doesn't give you an error because you are either using an older version of mysql, or are running in compatibility mode.

Comment: I try to run this query query on sql server too (online editor) but its works their also ..

Comment: Can you post the link to the online sql server editor?

Comment: i am try it on w3school.com

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in this is the link where i am trying to run " select min(quantity),* from orderDetails group by orderid"  this sql and it's executed  @HoneyBadger

Comment: That is webSQL, not sql server.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Hope this documentation helps you

> MySQL extends the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so that the select list
>   can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>   You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding
>   unnecessary column sorting and grouping. The server is free to choose
>   any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values
>   chosen are indeterminate.